# Textures do not render on ATI graphics cards?

Tags: xna, hlsl

I'm rendering textured quads to an orthographic view in XNA through hardware instancing. On Nvidia graphics cards, this all works, tested on 3 machines. On ATI cards, it doesn't work at all, tested on 2 machines.

How come? Culling perhaps?

My orthographic view is set up like this:

```
Matrix projection = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0, graphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, -graphicsDevice.Viewport.Height, 0, 0, 1);
```

And my elements are rendered with the Z-coordinate 0.

**Edit:**

I just figured out something weird.

If I do not call this spritebatch code above doing my textured quad rendering code, then it won't work on Nvidia cards either. Could that be due to culling information or something like that?

```
        Batch.Instance.SpriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.LinearClamp, DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullNone);
        ...
        spriteBatch.End();
```

**Edit 2:**

Here's the full code for my instancing call.

```
    public void DrawTextures()
    {

        Batch.Instance.SpriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Texture, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.LinearClamp, DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullNone, textureEffect);
        while (texturesToDraw.Count > 0)
        {
            TextureJob texture = texturesToDraw.Dequeue();
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture.Texture, texture.DestinationRectangle, texture.TintingColor);
        }
        spriteBatch.End();

#if !NOTEXTUREINSTANCING
        // no work to do
        if (positionInBufferTextured > 0)
        {

            device.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;

            textureEffect.CurrentTechnique = textureEffect.Techniques["Technique1"];
            textureEffect.Parameters["Texture"].SetValue(darkTexture);
            textureEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();

            if ((textureInstanceBuffer == null) ||
                (positionInBufferTextured > textureInstanceBuffer.VertexCount))
            {
                if (textureInstanceBuffer != null)
                    textureInstanceBuffer.Dispose();

                textureInstanceBuffer = new DynamicVertexBuffer(device, texturedInstanceVertexDeclaration, positionInBufferTextured, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
            }

            if (positionInBufferTextured > 0)
            {
                textureInstanceBuffer.SetData(texturedInstances, 0, positionInBufferTextured, SetDataOptions.Discard);
            }

            device.Indices = textureIndexBuffer;
            device.SetVertexBuffers(textureGeometryBuffer, new VertexBufferBinding(textureInstanceBuffer, 0, 1));

            device.DrawInstancedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, 0, 0, textureGeometryBuffer.VertexCount, 0, 2, positionInBufferTextured);

            // now that we've drawn, it's ok to reset positionInBuffer back to zero,
            // and write over any vertices that may have been set previously.
            positionInBufferTextured = 0;

        }
#endif
    }
```

Comment: Are your textures powers of 2?

Comment: [Don't use singletons in XNA](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13723/xna-static-classes-from-game-libraries-executing-after-content-pipeline-extensi/13763#13763)

Comment: Also, if you simply want to use the default values, pass `null` for that parameter to `SpriteBatch.Begin()` (works for everything but `SpriteSortMode`)

Comment: "I'm rendering textured quads to an orthographic view in XNA through hardware instancing." <- Why not just use `SpriteBatch`?

Comment: Andrew - because some of these quads must have the shader applied to it. Some of them doesn't. And I want to draw them in a single call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SpriteSortMode.Immediate` is setting the device state "immediately" you call `Begin`. You shouldn't use it unless you actually want the `Immediate` behaviour. Using `Immediate` turns off batching (slower) but allows you to directly manipulate states on the `GraphicsDevice` object between sprites. (Prefer `Deferred` instead.)

You are setting `DepthStencilState.Default` (depth reads and writes enabled), which is the default for `GraphicsDevice`, but the default for `SpriteBatch` is actually `None` (depth reads and writes disabled).

Now here's the bit where I have to **guess** (because you haven't provided enough code, and this is a tricky hardware-dependent problem):

You've set your near plane to `0`, and you're drawing things at a Z-position of 0, which is right on the border of the valid region of the depth buffer. I would hazard a guess it has something to do with this. You might try moving your near plane back, moving your Z-position forward, and/or disabling the depth buffer.

Comment: The SpriteSortMode thing was quite interesting. However, modifying the Z position didn't work at all.

Comment: I added more details in the original post.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this is exactly right, in XNA4 (as far as I understand) all SpriteBatch.Begin(...) calls immediately set some device states that you might have to reset afterwards. The only thing SpriteSortMode.Immediately changes is if the calls are done immediately on the graphics device or if the calls are batched until SpriteBatch.End() is called. However I know Andrew is quite a lot deeper into XNA than I am, I feel like I had to point this out.

Comment: The entire state gets set in `Begin` for `Immediate` and in `End` (just before everything is drawn) for every other sort mode. The idea is that you can start filling a (non-immediate) `SpriteBatch` in parallel with other drawing operations. It basically acts as a buffer. Also `SpriteBatch` doesn't ever reset state when it's finished ([ref](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/06/18/spritebatch-and-renderstates-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx)). In 3.1, `Immediate` was draw-lazy (fastest), in 4.0 it's draw-always (slowest, no batching).

Comment: I tried moving the Z coordinate to "5" or "0.5" etc. Still no result!

Answer (score 2):

Be careful, NVIDIA silently upgrades your incorrect set pixelshader/vertexshader versions.
ATI will fail.
Use the DirectX SDK to check for warnings.
My pixelshader was set to 3.0 and my (spriteBatch) Vertex shader to 2.0...