# How do I access variables in the Game1 class from another class in XNA?

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0, sprites, management

I'm trying to write a `SpriteManager` class in XNA, but I need access to the `Game` variables. For example, the `Game.Content` property would be very helpful in loading textures, and `Game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport` would be helpful in getting the window size.

For now, I have the following class:

```
public MainGame : DrawableGameComponent
{
    public SpriteManager<Enemy> EnemyManager { get; get; }
    public SpriteManager<Powerup> PowerupManager { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I can think of three ways of getting access to these variables in the `SpriteManager` class:

1. Make my sprite manager class derive off of `GameComponent`. This would be ideal, except that my sprite manager is used in `MainGame`, which is a `GameComponent`.
2. Use `((Game) Game1)` to access the variables. However, doing this kind of cast is ugly and breaks encapsulation.
3. Pass everything down from `MainGame`. For example, `EnemyManager` needs to load a random enemy type each time it spawns an enemy, so instead of loading the textures in `MainGame`, pass `EnemyManager` the `Game.Content` property and let it handle texture loading. However, I'm not sure if this is the best way of handling the situation. I can't place my finger on it, but it just seems 'wrong'  in some way.

I could use some advice on the best way of achieving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do that - [make the sprite manager a service](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13723/xna-static-classes-from-game-libraries-executing-after-content-pipeline-extensi/13763#13763) instead.

Comment: Thanks, this is the first I've heard of game services. It looks similar to dependency injection, but I'm only slightly familiar with it.

Comment: @Daniel: Dependency injection and service containers are two types of [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_Control).  See [this answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14217/several-classes-need-to-access-the-same-data-where-should-the-data-be-declared/14232#14232) for more details.

Comment: Everyone is so quick to make it a game service. It's not that bad to make it public. You only have 1 game instance ..

Answer (score 2):

Actually #2 isn't so bad (I will assume you meant to down-cast from `Game` to `Game1`). You can enforce the type being `Game1` in your constructor like so:

```
public MainGame : DrawableGameComponent
{
    public MainGame(Game1 game) : base(game) { }
}
```

You could even make a nice convenience property like this. It will always be safe, providing the underlying `DrawableGameComponent` doesn't do anything undocumented.

```
public Game1 Game1 { get { return (Game1)Game; } }
```

Or if you want to be extremely anal about not casting (and there is really **no need** to be), you could do this:

```
public MainGame : DrawableGameComponent
{
    public MainGame(Game1 game) : base(game) { this.Game1 = game; }

    public Game1 Game1 { get; private set; }
}
```