# I want to get rid of my make-everything-static-and-global design pattern, but how?

Tags: c#, architecture, design-patterns

I'm making a little dungeon crawler in space, and I'd like to hear some advice on how to make the backend of the engine nicer. Basically, currently everything is based on a crapload of managers:

- BackgroundManager: has `AddBackground(image, parallax)` method for making cool background effects.
- ConfigManager: reads/makes the config file and also holds the data read from that config file.
- DrawManager: has `Draw(sprite)` method to draw stuff to the screen, and things like `SetView(view)`, `GetView()` etc.
- EntityManager: holds all active entities and has methods for adding, removing and finding entities.
- DungeonManager (actually called a GridManager, but this is for simplicity): has methods like `GenerateDungeon()`, `PlaceEnemies()`, `PlaceFinish()` etc.

Now I'm not even halfway there listing all my managers, so I think this has got to change. My game is also based on Screens, which makes it more annoying because I don't need half of the stuff my managers are managing in, for example, the main menu (I don't need physics/entities/dungeons in my main menu!)

Now I thought about making the managers not static, and giving my ScreenMainGame an instance of all game-specific managers. But that makes calling/getting anything related to the managers a huge mess... for example, if I wanted to draw my dungeon from any place that's not in `ScreenMainGame.Draw()`, I'd have to do this...

```
((ScreenMainGame)ScreenManager.CurrentScreen).GridManager.Draw()
```

That's really ugly.

So, fellow game developers, does any of you have an idea how to solve this mess? I'd be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to help you, but I would recommend reading a good book on design patterns. I've been reading Head First Design Patterns and it's very easy to understand. The examples are in Java, but I think that would be close enough to C# to help you. Sorry if my suggestion is too novice.

Comment: What are you using to interface with the graphics card?  XNA?  SlimDX?

Comment: @BlueRaja: I'm using SFML.NET.

Comment: In that case, you should simply use the normal methods of dealing with these problems in C#:  See my last link below, as well as [What is dependency injection?](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Dependency-Injection-By-Hand)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about a [component-based engine](http://roecode.wordpress.com/xna-gameengine-development-series/)?

You would have a main class named `Engine`, which would keep a list of `GameScreens`, which would themselves hold a list of `Components`.

The engine has an `Update` and a `Draw` method and both call the `GameScreen`'s `Update` and `Draw` methods, which themselves go through every component and call `Update` and `Draw`.

Presented like that, I agree that it sounds like a poor and repetitive design. But believe me, my code became much cleaner by using a component-based approach than it did with all my old *manager* classes.

It's much simpler to maintain such code too, since you're just going through a big class hierarchy and not having to search through `BackgroundManager` for all the specific different backgrounds. You just have a `ScrollingBackground`, `ParallaxBackground`, `StaticBackground`, etc. which all derive from a `Background` class.

You'll eventually build up a pretty solid engine that you can reuse over all your projects with a lot of frequently used components and helper methods (e.g. a `FrameRateDisplayer` as a debugging utility, a `Sprite` class as a basic sprite with a texture and extension methods for vectors and random number generation).

You would no longer have a `BackgroundManager` class, but a `Background` class which would manage itself instead.

When your game starts, all you have to do is this basically:

```
// when declaring variables:
Engine engine;

// when initializing:
engine = new Engine();
engine.Initialize();
engine.LoadContent();
engine.AddGameScreen(new MainMenuScreen());

// when updating:
engine.Update();

// when drawing:
engine.Draw();
```

And that's it for your game start code.

Then, for the main menu screen:

```
class MainMenuScreen : MenuScreen // where MenuScreen derives from the GameScreen class
{
    const int ENEMY_COUNT = 10;

    StaticBackground background;
    Player player;
    List<Enemy> enemies;

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        background = new StaticBackground();
        player = new Player();
        enemies = new List<Enemy>();

        base.AddComponent(background); // defined within the GameScreen class
        base.AddComponent(player);
        for (int i = 0; i < ENEMY_COUNT; ++i)
        {
            Enemy newEnemy = new Enemy();
            enemies.Add(newEnemy);
            base.AddComponent(newEnemy);
        }
    }
}
```

You get the general idea.

You would also keep the reference of the `Engine` within all your `GameScreen` classes, to be able to add new screens even within a `GameScreen` class (e.g. when the user clicks on the *StartGame* button while within your `MainMenuScreen`, you can transition to the `GameplayScreen`).

The same goes for the `Component` class: it should hold the reference of its parent `GameScreen`, to have both access to the `Engine` class and its parent `GameScreen` to add new components (e.g. you can make a HUD-related class called `DrawableButton` which holds a 
`DrawableText` component and a `StaticBackground` component).

You can even apply other design patterns after that, like the "service design pattern"(not sure about the exact name) where you can keep different useful services within your `Engine` class(you simply keep a list of `IService`s and let other classes add services themselves). e.g. I would keep a `Camera2D` component over all my project as a service to apply its transformation when drawing other components. This avoids having to pass it as a parameter everywhere.

In conclusion, there certainly may be other better designs for an engine, but I found the engine proposed by [this link](http://www.innovativegames.net/blog/blog/2009/10/18/innovation-engine-roadmap-2009-2010/) very elegant, extremely easily maintainable and reusable. I would personally recommend at least trying it.

Comment: XNA supports all of this out-of-the-box via `GameComponent`s and services.  No need for a separate `Engine` class.

Comment: +1 for this answer. Also, would it make sense to put drawing in a separate thread from game update thread?

Comment: @BlueRaja - DannyPflughoeft: Indeed but I assumed XNA was not used so I explained a little bit more about how to do it.

Comment: @f20k: Yes, pretty much the same way XNA does it. I don't know how it is implemented though. =/ There must be an article somewhere on the internet about how to do it. :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not using XNA but this seems like a nice alternative to what I'm doing. I'm currently reading the book "Head First Design Patterns" to see if there are any more alternatives. Cheers!

Comment: -1 the answer has nothing to do with a component based system. It doesnt solve the problem at all. All you did was creating a god object that does all what the managers did before, thats not an improvment design wise. People seem to upvote nowadays, just because they read "components"

Comment: @Maik Semder: It follows the general idea of every component managing itself. I find it much better than OP's solution or at least I found my code to be much cleaner after following such a solution.

Comment: FYI @f20k separating drawing into another thread is usually impractical because of how close-knit it is to component state

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is separate your code into components and services.  XNA has built-in support for these already.

See [this article](http://www.nuclex.org/articles/4-architecture/6-game-components-and-game-services) on `GameComponents` and services.  Then see [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13723/xna-static-classes-from-game-libraries-executing-after-content-pipeline-extensi/13763#13763) on using services in XNA, and [this more general answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14217/several-classes-need-to-access-the-same-data-where-should-the-data-be-declared/14232#14232) on services in any language.

Answer (score -3):

Just because they are static or global doesn't mean they have to always be loaded/initialized. Use a Singleton pattern and allow the managers to be freeable and loaded again on demand.

Comment: A singleton is just a facade for the underlying problem the OP is trying to solve here.